# Audiocontext was not allowed to start in lib-jitsi-meet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api, autoplay, jitsi

I'm developing a video chat application using lib-jitsi-meet. It's all working fine in Firefox, but when it comes to Chrome, it throws the following error in the console.

> lib-jitsi-meet.min.js:1 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.

The participant can't use the microphone in the Chrome browser because of this error. I know this is related to the changes in Chrome autoplay policies. I could've done something if I'm using the pure web audio API, however, I couldn't understand what should I do to avoid this in lib-jitsi-meet.

I searched for this error in Jitsi community forums and many other places but didn't find any helpful answer to circumvent this.

How can I overcome this issue so that video chat participants from the Chrome browser can use their microphones and hear what others are saying? Thank you for all the helpful suggestions.

Comment: wow, this has been the case for 2 years at least - and jitsi haven't addressed it at all in that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs with [Jitsi Meet NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lib-jitsi-meet-dist). Upon importing it to my React app as

```js
import JitsiMeetJS from 'lib-jitsi-meet-dist'
```

it automatically creates a new `AudioContext` object. Since that is not allowed in Chrome due to its autoplay policies, I cannot either access the microphone or listen to other participants. I could've resumed the created `AudioContext` and go on, but there was no way to do that in the library.

As a solution, I added the Jitsi Meet library as a script in the `index.html` of my React app and used the `JitsiMeetJS` object in the app as `window.JitsiMeetJS`.

```js
<script src="https://meet.jit.si/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"></script>
```

With that approach, there was still an `AudioContext` object initialized, but it's related to something called collecting local stats, not Jitsi Meet core functionality. Therefore, I could ignore it and move on.